# SQL search for only one LEFT item

Tags: sql, performance

My SQL query really takes a lot of time, so I thought there might be a better way of writing it.

The table "Vorgangdetails" has an item, which has a number in "RecId". This number might be in a different row in "WeiterfuehrungVonPos". If so this new row has a number in "RecId", which might be again in a different row in "WeiterfuehrungVonPos" ... (overall up to 3 times)
My query simply takes way too long. Do know a faster way?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(VD_AB.Menge) AS Amount,
    Artikel.Artikelnummer AS Artikelnummer,
FROM Artikel

    INNER JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_AB
        ON LEFT(VD_AB.Auftrag, 3) = 'AF-'
        AND Artikel.Artikelnummer = VD_AB.Artikel
```

--> adding maximum 1 result from the same table as VD_AB

```
    LEFT JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_L
        ON LEFT(VD_L.Auftrag, 3) = 'LF-'
        AND Artikel.Artikelnummer = VD_L.Artikel
        AND VD_L.WeiterfuehrungVonPos = VD_AB.RecId
```

--> again ... adding maximum 1 result from the same table as VD_AB

```
    LEFT JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_RvL
        ON VD_L.RecID = VD_RvL.WeiterfuehrungVonPos
        AND LEFT(VD_RvL.Auftrag, 3) = 'RE-'
```

--> again ... adding maximum 1 result from the same table as VD_AB

```
    LEFT JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_RvAB
        ON VD_AB.RecID = VD_RvAB.WeiterfuehrungVonPos
        AND LEFT(VD_RvAB.Auftrag, 3) = 'RE-'

WHERE (VD_RvAB.Auftrag = '' AND VD_RvL.Auftrag = '')

GROUP BY(Artikelnummer)
```

.
    .

Final RESULT) --------------  edited to reflect all answers from Roman Pekar

```
SELECT 
    SUM(VD_AB.Menge) AS Auftragsmenge,
    Artikel.Artikelnummer AS Artikelnummer,
FROM Artikel
    INNER JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_AB
        ON VD_AB.Auftrag LIKE 'AB-%'
        AND Artikel.Artikelnummer = VD_AB.Artikel
    LEFT JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_L
        ON Artikel.Artikelnummer = VD_L.Artikel
        AND VD_L.WeiterfuehrungVonPos = VD_AB.RecId
        AND (VD_L.Auftrag LIKE 'LF-%' OR VD_L.Auftrag LIKE 'RE-%')
    LEFT JOIN Vorgangdetails AS VD_RvL
        ON VD_L.Auftrag is not null
        AND VD_L.Auftrag LIKE 'LF-%'
        AND VD_L.RecID = VD_RvL.WeiterfuehrungVonPos
        AND VD_RvL.Auftrag LIKE 'RE-%'
WHERE (Artikel.Kategorie = 'KARSTADT->Aktive')
    AND (VD_L.Auftrag LIKE 'LF-%' AND VD_RvL.Auftrag = '')
    AND NOT (VD_L.Auftrag LIKE 'RE-%')
GROUP BY(Artikelnummer)
```

Comment: which RDBMS you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - avoid using functions on columns participating in joins, the query cannot utilize index when you do so.
Next, try to check if you actually have indexes on columns on which you join tables.

You can use like comparison when you want to compare just a part of string. Here the query for SQL Server (I don't know which RDBMS you using):

```
select
    sum(VD_AB.Menge) as Amount,
    Artikel.Artikelnummer as Artikelnummer,
from Artikel
    inner join Vorgangdetails as VD_AB on
        VD_AB.Auftrag like 'AF-%' and VD_AB.Artikel = Artikel.Artikelnummer
    left outer join Vorgangdetails as VD_L on
        VD_L.Auftrag like 'LF-%' and VD_L.Artikel = Artikel.Artikelnummer and
        VD_L.WeiterfuehrungVonPos = VD_AB.RecId
    left outer join Vorgangdetails as VD_RvL on
        VD_RvL.Auftrag like 'RE-%' and
        VD_RvL.WeiterfuehrungVonPos = VD_L.RecID and
        VD_L.Auftrag is not null
    left outer join Vorgangdetails as VD_RvAB on
        VD_RvAB.Auftrag like 'RE-%' and
        VD_RvAB.WeiterfuehrungVonPos = VD_AB.RecID
where VD_RvAB.Auftrag = '' and VD_RvL.Auftrag = ''
group by Artikelnummer
```

Comment: That cut the time by 8. Nice.
But still I am over 130 seconds. 
Is it possible to bring this further down. 
I always just need to search for one result, ...
 Can I call an IF case to determine if I need a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: how many numbers do you have in your tables? do you have indexes?

Comment: I mean rows, not numbers

Comment: I have about 200.000 rows in the most used table.

Comment: Could I add the VD_RvL only if the VD_L is like 'LF-%'? Is that possible? That would really - I mean really bring it down.

Comment: added `AND VD_L.Auftrag is not null` into the join, try it

Comment: I updated my original post and added what I have so far at the bottom.
Is "is not null" faster than LIKE 'LF-%'?

Comment: I updated my original post to show the final result. This last line you suggested really rocks. GREAT . THANKS .